# Is this a natural metric on the space of all unoriented lines in a 2D place with positive slope?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Let's parameterize a 2D (unoriented) line by the slope $m$ and intercept $b$, and let the slope be positive. Thus, we are looking at all lines in the first quadrant. I want to know if there's a natural way to measure distances between lines or the "size" of a line in the $(m,b)$ space. I know that there's no natural metric on the space of all possible unoriented lines, but I wonder if there exists one for the restricted case I have described above. Here's how I am reasoning about it for now.

Two lines with the same slope are different only by the intercept $b$, so that's trivial. Next, two lines with the same intercept differ by the angle $\theta=\arctan(m)$. So, am I correct in thinking that the 2D polar coordinate system is the natural coordinate system here? If so, then can I use $b^2+b^2\theta^2$ as a metric?

Comment: Your metric should take two points as input and return a distance, so you want a formula of the form $d((b_1,\theta_1),(b_2,\theta_2))=$ something.  Then you need to verify that it meets the requirements of a metric-distance is nonnegative and positive when the points are different, symmetry, and the triangle inequality.  It sounds like you want $(b_1-b_2)^2(1+(\theta_1-\theta_2)^2)$.  The only problem is the triangle inequality.

Comment: Can you explain which properties a "natural metric" should have?